# Pattern matching space character

Tags: prolog

Here is my problem:

```
etp(V W,[V W|G]).
etp(W V,[V W|G]).
etp(V W,[_|G]):- etp(V W,G).
```

Prolog says `Syntax error: Operator expected`. I tried to escape the blank symbol like `'\s'`, `"\s"` and couple other possibilities which I figured out should work. Well, neither did not work properly. What's the right way to escape space character to match e.g.: `etp(A B,[A B,C D].`

Edit:
List is created in following way:

```
read_line(L,C) :-
    get_char(C),
    (isEOFEOL(C), L = [], !;
        read_line(LL,_),% atom_codes(C,[Cd]),
        [C|LL] = L).

%Tests if character is EOF or LF.
isEOFEOL(C) :-
    C == end_of_file;
    (char_code(C,Code), Code==10).

read_lines(Ls) :-
    read_line(L,C),
    ( C == end_of_file, Ls = [] ;
      read_lines(LLs), Ls = [L|LLs]
    ).
```

So it reads a input which looks like

```
A B
C D
E F
G H
```

And `read_lines(L)` returns L = [[A, ,B],[C, ,D],[E, ,F],[G, ,H]].
That's how I get those spaces between them.
Well I actually need to replace the `, ,` by `-`, which I tried to do:

```
read_line(L,C) :-
    get_char(C),
    ( (char_code(C,Code), Code == 32)
        -> C = '-'
        ; C = C),
    (isEOFEOL(C), L = [], !;
        read_line(LL,_),% atom_codes(C,[Cd]),
        [C|LL] = L).
```

And Prolog says `Syntax error: Unexpected end of file`. Don't know whats wrong.

Comment: You can never put Prolog variables side by side. They must always be connected by some operator or separated by some punctuation. A space is neither. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Because I got list which looks like [A B,C D,E F,G H], as you can see, there's a space between them chars (atoms).

Comment: That is not a valid Prolog list. Where is it from?

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie I just edited the question.

Comment: That code gives `L = [['A', ' ', 'B'], ['C', ' ', 'D'], ['E', ' ', 'F'], ['G', ' ', 'H']]`. Do you really not see all the single quotes and commas? To match one of these things, use `etp([V, ' ', W], [[V, ' ', W] | G]).` and so on.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Yeah, there is actually a lot more code then I posted. So if I wanted to modify it as you say, that would be pretty laborious. Better option is to replace the `' '` by  `'-'`.

Comment: Please open a new question for the problem with the `read_line` predicate.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Ok, [I just did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079900/list-of-lists-into-modified-single-list).